# How do I filter columns in unix

Tags: unix

My query is I have a csv file that has 11 columns.i want to extract records that have 7 columns with numbers .Please note 7th column has strings as well as numbers.tried with awk command but did not work

Comment: Please, post some sample data with expected output along with what you have already tried.

Answer (score 5):

```
cat file.csv | awk '{print $7}'| egrep -v [a-z]+
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want the lines with 7 column as numbers ?

You can use grep to do that. With ',' as separator :

```
grep ".*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,[0-9]*,.*" yourfile.csv
```

if you want the 7 column only, use cut  (-d => delimiter, -f select field)

```
cat yourfile | cut -d, -f7 | grep "[0-9]*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider `column` tool.
To for example print only the first 7 columns of 11 column csv file, you would execute

```bash
column -H 8,9,10,11 your_file.csv
```

Afaik there is no way to specify it using a range

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're specifically looking for a bash command, but I'd recommend using a scripting language like python for it. One way to do it in python is:

```
count = 0
prunedColumns = []
with open('FILENAME','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count = 0
        for entry in line.split(','):
            try:
                float(entry)
                count += 1
            except ValueError:
                continue
            if count == 7:
                prunedColumns.append(line)
print(prunedColumns)
```

Comment: Let's say the file is :


Abc;123;aaaa;789
Pqr;567;5555;999
Xyz;888;bbbb;6453
Lmn;777;5555;8989




I am expecting output to have column 2 , (column 3 with only numbers)

Answer (score 0):

First some test data:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c d  # seven numbers, a hit
1 2 3 4 5 6 a b c d e  # six, a miss
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 a b c  # eight, a miss
1 2 3 4 5 6 7a b c d e # seven, a hit
```

In awk:

```
$ awk '{
    for((i=1)&&c=0;i<=NF;i++)  # check each field
        if($i~/[0-9]+/)        # if there are numbers in it
            c++                # iterate counter
} 
c==7                           # if there are 7 fields, print record
' file                      
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c d  # seven numbers, a hit
1 2 3 4 5 6 7a b c d e # seven, a hit
```

Answer (score 0):

try one more approach here, using same Input_file as James Brown used in his post.

```
awk '{val=$0;if(gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",val)==7){print}}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c d  # seven numbers, a hit
1 2 3 4 5 6 7a b c d e # seven, a hit
```

Comment: I am looking for 7th column specifically that has numbers in some rows and string in other columns

Comment: @shikha: Could you please add sample Input_file and expected output into your post with code tags, it will be really helpful for us to help you then.